# Gsutil rm does not remove everything

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a problem with one of my automated jobs. 
Before launching a cloud dataflow job, I perform a gsutil rm on previous files but it appears that it does not remove everything because when I launch another dataflow job some older shards remain.

I tried :

```
gsutil -m rm gs://mybucket/blahblah/*
```

and

```
gsutil rm -r gs://mybucket/blablah
```

But same result...

Strange thing is that not removed files are nor the first nor the last.
I tought it was my second job fault but the fact is that I saw in logs that indeed files were not removed bu gsutil.

Is there possibility that there is too many files to delete ?
Is there known problems of gsutil rm reliability ?

I use version 0.9.80 of google cloud sdk

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gsutil rm commands you're using depend on listing the objects in a bucket, which is an eventually consistent operation in Google Cloud Storage. Thus, it's possible that attempting these commands in a bucket soon after objects were written will not remove all the objects. If you try again later it should succeed.

One way to avoid this problem would be to keep track of the names of the objects you uploaded, and explicitly list those objects in the gsutil rm command. For example, if you kept the object list in the file objects.manifest you could run a command like this on Linux or MacOS:

```
xargs gsutil -m rm < objects.manifest
```

Comment: gsutil rm also supports a -I flag which accepts a list of objects on stdin .

Comment: Travis' answer is better because it can be used on any OS (including Windows).